# MySQL: How to GROUP BY a field to retrieve the rows with ORDER BY another field?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

assume following data:

**Data:**

```
    id  |   date        |   name    |   grade
--------+---------------+-----------+---------------
    1   | 2010/12/03    |   Mike    |   12
    2   | 2010/12/04    |   Jenny   |   12
    3   | 2010/12/04    |   Ronald  |   15
    4   | 2010/12/03    |   Yeni    |   11
```

i want to know who has the best grade in each day, something like this:

**Desired Result:**

```
    id  |   date        |   name    |   grade
--------+---------------+-----------+---------------
    1   | 2010/12/03    |   Mike    |   12
    3   | 2010/12/04    |   Ronald  |   15
```

i thought query should look like this:

```
SELECT name FROM mytable
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY grade DESC
```

but it returns something like this:

**Current Unwanted Result:**

```
    id  |   date        |   name    |   grade
--------+---------------+-----------+---------------
    1   | 2010/12/03    |   Mike    |   12
    2   | 2010/12/04    |   Jenny   |   12
```

i searched and i found the reason:

**GROUP BY happens before ORDER BY so it does not see and can't apply ORDER.**

so how can i apply ORDER on GROUP BY?

**Note:** please keep in mind that i need the most simple query,  because my query is actually very complex, i know i can achieve this result by some subquery or JOINing, but i want to know how to apply ORDER to GROUP BY. thanks

Comment: You will need to use a subquery, as you state Group occurs before order.

Answer (score 2):

I used Oracle for this example, but the SQL should work in mysql (you may need to tweak the to_date stuff to work with mysql). You really need a subquery here to do what you are asking.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (ID NUMBER, dt DATE, NAME VARCHAR2(25), grade NUMBER);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1,to_date('2010-12-03','YYYY-MM-DD'),'Mike',12);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1,to_date('2010-12-04','YYYY-MM-DD'),'Jenny',12);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1,to_date('2010-12-04','YYYY-MM-DD'),'Ronald',15);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1,to_date('2010-12-03','YYYY-MM-DD'),'Yeni',11);

    SELECT id
         , dt
         , name
         , grade
      FROM mytable t1
     WHERE grade = (SELECT max(grade)
                      FROM mytable t2
                     WHERE t1.dt = t2.dt)
    ORDER BY dt
```

Results:

```
ID  DT          NAME   GRADE
1   12/3/2010   Mike   12
2   12/4/2010   Ronald 15
```

Comment: thank, it seems that these queries and results are real. and it seems you've forgotten the DESC in ORDER BY, may you correct and send the result again. your current result is exactly what i got now.

Comment: @takpar - Sorry for that, when inserting the test data I didn't have 15 for Ronald, which is why the results were wrong. So the query was correct, but my test data insert code was wrong :). Also, we don't want DESC on the order by, because then the dates will come back in reverse order (e.g. newest date will come back before oldest date). According to your desired result, you want the dates in ascending order, and ASC is the default option on an order by so it doesn't need to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you wanted a GROUP / ORDER only solution but you will need to use a subquery in this instance.  The simplest way would be something like this:

```
SELECT id, date, name, grade
FROM   mytable t1
WHERE grade = 
(SELECT MAX(t2.grade) FROM mytable t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
```

This would show multiple students if they shared the highest grade for the day.