# How do I group existing table rows and then apply order by

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I would like to group column values and then order values in another column in ascending order. I don't mind if new table has to be created. Could any one help me with this query please? Database is MySQL.

Thanks so much!

Please see my sample data here.

### SID | Area-No | Sub-Area No|

### 1-------5-----------1------|

### 2-------4-----------1------|

### 3-------3-----------2------|

### 9-------5-----------2------|

### 5-------6-----------1------|

### 7-------9-----------3------|

### 4-------1-----------9------|

### 6-------1-----------7------|

### 8-------2-----------1------|

### 10------2-----------5------|

### 11------2-----------6------|

### 12------2-----------2------|

Each SID has an Area-No. There are 1-20+ Areas. Each Area has 1-20+ sub-Areas. I want to group SIDs by Area No, so that table is re-arranged (or may be new table is created) which has first few rows showing only Area 1 and all Sub-Areas under Area 1. Then rows show Area2 and all sub areas under Area 2, so on. I dont mind if SIDs order change.

Output would be:

### SID | Area-No | Sub-Area No|

### 6-------1-----------7------|

### 4-------1-----------9------|

### 8-------2-----------1------|

### 12------2-----------2------|

### 10------2-----------5------|

### 11------2-----------6------|

### 3-------3-----------2------|

### 2-------4-----------1------|

### 1-------5-----------1------|

### 9-------5-----------2------|

### 5-------6-----------1------|

### 7-------9-----------3------|

Select returns records to me. But I want to arrange the table itself, not selecting records from it. I dont mind if new table has to be created.

Thanks again!!

Comment: possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983/sql-group-by-with-an-order-by)

Comment: Posting your table structure, some sample data and the desired result would be helpful.

Comment: Show an example of the table you have and tell us the columns you want to group and sort by.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to GROUP BY a field to retrieve the rows with ORDER BY another field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267872/mysql-how-to-group-by-a-field-to-retrieve-the-rows-with-order-by-another-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. I just had to start with ordering by the column I want, here Area and subArea.

```
insert into temp select * from stuTable order by Area, subArea;
```

Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: I can't think of any good reason why you should rearrange the order of data in your table except for where it is based on a primary key. A database table isn't designed to be viewed as is - but rather selected upon in the order or grouping that the view requires.

Answer (score 0):

its simple query .

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM table_name  
GROUP BY column_name 
ORDER BY column_name
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to reorder or rearrange the table itself, not selecting. I'd select later after it is rearranged. Please let me know if this helps now.